# Python ipywidgets - empty widget that can be filled inside a function

Tags: python, function, drop-down-menu, ipywidgets

Let's say I have a dropdown widget with some numbers and a floatext widget with some other numbers. I would like to define a widget that takes an empty parameter and can be dynamically filled with the calculation made inside the function which in this case would be mW.

I could do it by **not defining** the mW widget and returning this inside the function but I was hoping for another way.

```
dW = Dropdown(options = [1, 2, 3, 4])
rW = FloatText(200)
mW = ...... empty widget to be filled with the calculation made inside the fuction

@interact(D=dW, R=rW, mW=M)
def print_p(D, R):
    dW = D
    rW = R
    mW = D*R
```

My expected outcome would be the below with 400 or another number calculated dynamically filled in the M box.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:

> "Defining a widget that takes an empty parameter and can be
> dynamically filled with the calculation made inside the function"

You can simply use a `FloatText` widget with ***no parameters***, and then ***setting the value inside the function***; as follows:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

dW = widgets.Dropdown(options=['2', '1'])
rW = widgets.FloatText(200)
mW = widgets.FloatText()             #empty widget

@interact(D=dW, R=rW, M= mW)

def print_p(D, R, M):
    dW = D
    rW = R
    mW.value = int(dW)*int(rW)      #now i set the value of the empty widget
```

Then, for **dinamically checking the value** of `mW`, you can use the `threading` library:

```
import threading
```

For any doubt:

- [threading library](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/)
- [ipywidgets documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it seems working even without threading, just by using .value!

Comment: I am happy to have helped you! if the answer was helpful in solving yours problem, could you mark it as correct answer? thank you a lot.